# php form validation and error messages

Tags: php, forms

I'm setting up this newsletter subscription form to communicate with my database, but before sending the information(email) I just want to validate it. However when I enter wrong or empty data, it displays both error messages. I'm no expert on PHP but it seems I'm missing some closing brackets or something.. I've fiddled around now for a while with no success, so I turn for help to you guys again :)

```
<?php
$host = "XXX";
$username = "name";
$password = "XXX";
$database = "base";
$connect = @mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (@mysql_error());
$selectdb = @mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die (@mysql_error());


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(empty($email)){
    echo "Hmm, you did not anything..";
    }
    if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
    $email_address))
    {
    echo "This email not valid";
    }
    else{
    @mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletters SET email='$email'");
    echo "Thanks you";
}

}
?>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You wrote `$email_address` in `preg_match`. Replace with `$email` and put `preg_match` condition out of `if(empty($email))`

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently using the following structure:

```
if (condition) {

}
if (condition) {

}
else (condition) {

}
```

Change the structure to:

```
if (condition) {

}
elseif (condition) {

}
else (condition) {

}
```

That way, the `elseif` statement will get executed ONLY if the first if statement evaluates to `FALSE`.

Also, in your `preg_match` statement, you're using the variable `$email_address` which isn't defined anywhere, as far as I can see.

Change it to `$email`:

```
if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
    $email))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

how about using it this way (did not check the RegEx):

```
if(empty($email)){
    echo "Hmm, you did not anything..";
}
else{
    if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
    $email_address)){
         echo "This email not valid";
    }
    else{
         @mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletters SET email='$email'");
         echo "Thanks you";
    }
}
```

That way it first checks if the email is inserted, only if that is true the regex checks it. If that is ready the query is sent to mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
if (!preg_match(
```

with

```
elseif (!preg_match(
```

Then only one of this errors is shown and the preg_match is first run when $email is not empty.